# Express the Midpoint of a Vector

Tags: vectors

[image]

I am struggling with part $b$ and $c$ of the question. I have done my working out so far however I am not sure where to go from there.

An explanation would be appreciated as I am trying to learn the process rather than just the answer alone.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder why the source of this document always transmogrifies "O"s to "0"s when placing them under ray signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) is correct!

For (c):

$O+\mathbf{b}+(\frac{1}{2}\vec{BA})=O+\mathbf{b}+\frac{1}{2}(-\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a})=O+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a})}_\text{this is $\vec{OM}$}=M$.

If this isn't clear, you can imagine it as the half way point between $a$ and $b$, so add them together and divide by two, in order to get the same result.

Now that we have an expression for $M$, we're almost done!

Comment: I think the question asks for $BM$ "floating" (as you describe it). Getting to the midpoint $M$ isn't called for in (b), but it does help with (c).

Comment: I'm an idiot, misread the question. Editing

Comment: You're correct! $\frac{1}{2}(b+a)$ is how to actually get to $M$.

Comment: @AndresMejia Would it not be $1/2(-b + a)?$

Comment: No, that would be the vector $\frac{1}{2}\vec{BA}=\vec{BM}$ as you have shown in your work.

Comment: Would the vector O to M be $b - \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}a$? @AndresMejia

Comment: yep, but notice the algebra done in my answer. This is the same as $\frac{1}{2}(b+a)$

Comment: Ah right. So would the vector O to N be $\frac{1}{2}a$...?

Comment: Not quite. If I give you an arbitrary vector $\vec{A}$, how do you find its midpoint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37592/discussion-between-perfectnutter-and-andres-mejia).

Comment: @AndresMejia The negative signs in OP's handwriting are unusually short. I think the illegible smudge to the left of $\frac12b$ on the last line of the work for part (b) is supposed to be a negative sign, that is, the answer at that point was $-\frac12b + \frac12a$. That's consistent with the previous lines of the work, although it's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer to (b) is correct (but the first line has a printo - you should write $BM = (1/2)BA$).

Hint for (c): draw the parallelogram with vertices $O$, $A$, $B$ and ... . Then find $OM$ and $ON$.

Comment: I agree with your hint for (c) though!, so +1

Comment: @AndresMejia I think the $-(1/2)b$ is right, since the vector from $B$ to $M$ is called for.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use the [parallelogram law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelogramLaw.html) for the sum of two vectors $\vec a,\vec b$ , and the theorem that states that the two diagonals of a parallelogram meet at the middle pont ( that is $M$).

And remember linearity: $\frac{1}{2}(\vec a +\vec b)=\frac{1}{2}\vec a +\frac{1}{2}\vec b$